# Ora-12514 TNS: Listener Error from Oracle Net Configuration Assistant

Tags: oracle, server

I am installing Oracle 11.2.0.4 database server per an installation procedure.  After installing, I create a database named SM3DDB using Database Configuration Assistant.  After creating database, I am able to log into database using Start->Application Development->SQL Plus with following details;

username: sys as sysdba

password: system

While logged in I successfully query name of database using

```
select name from v$database;
```

and get the database name:

SM3DDB

The next step of my installation procedure is to configure an Oracle Net Service by using Oracle Net Configuration Assistant with following steps:

1. Select Local Net Service Name configuration
2. Add
3. Enter Service Name in this case I used SM3DDBSRVC
4. Select TCP
5. Enter Computer Name and Select Next
6. Select Yes, Perform a Test
   I then get following error:

Connecting...ORA-12514: TNS:Listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor.  The test did not succeed.

Next I select change login and I try the test again using

username: sys

password: system

But I still get same error.  I repeated the test a few times using sys as sysdba, system, etc for username, but still getting same error.  Note that I am able to successfully log in to database using SQL Plus.
Why do I receive this error from Oracle Net Configuration Manager.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The service provided should be the database service name-also given on the window attached below- which is `SM3DDB`, you will be asked to provide Net Service Name after the test step.

Database service name can be obtained using following method.

```
SQL> show parameter service

NAME                     TYPE    VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
service_names                string  ORCL
```

[image]